# Как вывести плавной прокруткой RecyclerView с отдельным TextView?

Tags: java, android

Как вывести плавной прокруткой RecyclerView с отдельным TextView?

После некоторого времени у меня получилось вывести текст и список в прокрутке

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="fdsffddf"></TextView>



                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                    android:id="@+id/contact_recyclerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Но есть проблема когда делаю промотку, она автоматический не идет как обычно с receclerview, немного мотаешь она сразу останавливается, т.е. не плавная как будто тормозит.

незнаю на видео видно https://youtu.be/ZV4HTcQxwVE

короче она автоматический не прокручивается а останаваливается, а должа до конца прокручиваться при одном движении

Comment: Разметку добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: вопрос не очень понятен. вам нужны анимации появления виджетов? каким образом должен прокручиваться текст и где он? отредактируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы людям, ничего не знающим о вашей проблеме, тоже было понятно, в чем именно она заключается. добавьте скриншоты, как должно быть и как есть у вас, опишите подробно, что именно должно происходить, добавьте код, разметку, чтобы проблему можно было воспроизвести

Comment: Вот попытался объяснить

Comment: а зачем recyclerview внутри scrollview? добавьте еще разметку элемента списка на всякий.